# Paramiko SSHClient.connect(...) fails when packaged with Pyinstaller on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, paramiko

Paramiko's `SSHClient.connect(...)` method will raise an exception when packaged with Pyinstaller, but will run fine when not packaged.

This occurs using both of the Pyinstaller flags, `--onedir` and `--onefile`. I have tried Pyinstaller versions `3.5` and the current latest dev version, `4.0.dev0+ce887b462`. `--noupx` does not have a noticeable effect.

My Paramiko version is `2.6.0`.

My current Python version is `2.7.15`

My OS is Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.17134, Build 17134.

This issue seems to result from Paramiko calling a C function in `kernel32.dll`, which unexpectedly returns `null` only when packaged.

Minimal example:

```py
import paramiko

# The nature of this issue unfortunately requires
# a server that responds to SSH connections to test
host = None  # Put a valid hostname here
port = 22  # Put a valid port here

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(
    hostname=host,
    port=port,
    username=None,
    password=None,
    timeout=5
)
```

I expect the Pyinstaller-packaged version to run exactly the same as the unpackaged version -- in this case, to initiate a SSH connection, then fail with an AuthenticationException, since `username` and `password` are `None`:

```
> virtualenv venv
> venv\Scripts\activate.bat
> pip install pyinstaller==3.5 paramiko==2.6.0
[output truncated for brevity]
> pyinstaller minimal-paramiko-example.py
[output truncated for brevity]
> dist\minimal-paramiko-example\minimal-paramiko-example.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimal-paramiko-example.py", line 16, in <module>
    timeout=5
  File "site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 446, in connect
  File "site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 691, in _auth
  File "site-packages\paramiko\agent.py", line 379, in __init__
  File "site-packages\paramiko\agent.py", line 65, in _connect
  File "site-packages\paramiko\agent.py", line 82, in _send_message
  File "site-packages\paramiko\win_pageant.py", line 129, in send
  File "site-packages\paramiko\win_pageant.py", line 96, in _query_pageant
  File "site-packages\paramiko\_winapi.py", line 179, in write
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
[16768] Failed to execute script minimal-paramiko-example

> python minimal-paramiko-example.py  # Will result in an AuthenticationException, since username and password are None; this is expected and normal
[output truncated for brevity]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by an interaction with PuTTY Pageant. Closing PuTTY Pageant causes this error to not occur. For some reason, it only manifests in the corner case of:

- Using Pyinstaller
- Running PuTTY Pageant

Failing to satisfy both requirements will not trigger the issue.